# Add selectors to multiple segmented controls in NIB file

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol, target-action

I have two `UIbutton`s, and I want to assign the two buttons to a `UITextView` so that when one of the buttons is pressed, the text view content changes from what it had when previous button was pressed. I want to do this using a segmented control. How do I assign each segmented control different selectors in the NIB file?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you have to connect your IBAction to your `UISegmentedControl` in IB with the `valueChanged:` option (i think you usually set touchUpInside for uibuttons), then try this

```
- (IBAction)changeType:(id)sender{
    //segControl is an instance of UISegmentedControl
    segControl = sender;
    if(segControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0){
       //do something
    }
    else if (segControl.selectedSegmentIndex==1){

    }//and so on
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the segment control to a single `IBAction`. In that method use segment control's `selectedSegmentIndex` to identify which section is pressed and call the later functions accordingly.